# SharePoint filenames

Tags: sharepoint, moss

We all know MOSS is a royal pain in the gut. Today I am faced with yet another MOSS issue, file names.

Documents stored in a MOSS document library cannot contain the following characters in the filename: \ / : * ? " < > | # { } % ~ &

(1) Is it possible to apply a patch to MOSS to allow the same filenames as are permitted on a standard file system?

(2) If this is not possible is there some kind of adapter that can allow for this?

Thanks

Comment: Many of these characters just cant be used in a URL, which is what a file gets when you upload it to SharePoint. Not sure that this translates to SharePoint being a pain in the gut, your question would probably be better without subjective opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No.

2) You could possible develop customized upload and download functionality that would encode/decode the special characters and store them in a special way.

Comment: problem is the documents are from an official source, so I am not sure if renaming the files interferes with the official process.

Comment: @JL: You can always store the original filename in a property.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is wonderful! (I dunno, if you want answers why disrespect the product that the people answering may be experts in?)

It makes sense that those characters are not supported. ? for instance serves a very distinct purpose in urls so you can't use it anywhere you like in urls. Nothing to do with MOSS really. Its a browser based app, thats all.